# Windows Phone 8 panorama layouts

Tags: windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I'm new to Windows phone 8 development and I am having difficulty with a panorama view.

When I create a basic 'Windows Phone Portrait Page' I have no difficulty creating grids and aligning Toolbox controls between those grids.
However, with the Panorama page, when I create grids, those grids are applied to every page in the panorama and therefore I cannot use different layouts for each page.

How would I achieve different layouts on my panorama page?
Should I be using a WindowsPhoneControl instead?

Thanks for your time.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="SmarterPower.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="225*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="107*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="351*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="201*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="248*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <!--Panorama control-->
    <phone:Panorama Title="smarter power for you" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SmarterPower;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem>
            <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping using a floating header that scrolls with the content-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,-38,-22,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="12,0,0,38">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="menu"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle}"
                                       Grid.Row="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="50" Width="432">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                            <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-5,0,5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,5,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the XAML code from your app? This will let me see where the error is. Likely what is happening is you are nesting your new grid in the wrong spot.

Comment: I have updated as per your request. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: for future reference. Please don't ever post a question on stack without code. People tend to get really nasty when you do that. You should always post a problem, the code and what you have tried. I will take a look at the code and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why are you dividing the LayoutRoot in columns and rows, and not each Panorama Item? Which is your desired result?

Comment: Thanks @anderZubi, I tried to add grids to an individual panorama item without success. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Which is the problem? Which is the desired result?

Comment: If I attempt to add these grids inside the <phone:panorama item> tags:
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="180*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

... it complains that "Row definitions" is not recognized or accessible"

Comment: You have to define rows and columns inside a Grid control. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your rows and columns in a Grid control inside a panorama item, instead of defining them in the layout root grid:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">


    <!--Panorama control-->
    <phone:Panorama Title="My Panorama" >

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item 1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="225*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="107*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="351*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="201*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="248*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item 2">              
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I'm very grateful. Thanks, @anderZubi.